# Relacionar 3 tabelas no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Possuo 3 tabelas: `contratos`, `contratos_empresas` e `empresas`

No sistema existe um formulário para cadastro de contratos, nesse formulário existe um multiple select (que permite selecionar várias empresas ao mesmo tempo), os `<options>` desse select vem da tabela `empresas`, e como podem ser selecionadas várias empresas, a tabela `contratos` não possui um campo **empresa_id** e esses dados do select são salvos na tabela `contratos_empresas` salvando o **contrado_id** e o **empresa_id**.

Já existe uma relação do tipo **hasMany** no model do contrato, o que gostaria de fazer é ao selecionar as empresas, da tabela `contratos_empresas`, através do contrato, selecionar também as empresas em que o id forem iguais aos do `contrato_empresas`, é possível fazer isso?

Resumo para melhor entendimento:

`contrato_empresas` pertence tanto a `contratos` como `empresas`, e é ligado à essas tabelas através dos campos: **contrato_id** e **empresa_id**

Comment: Você quer selecionar somente as empresas que tiverem contratos. é isso?

Comment: Os contratos que tiverem empresas, dentro do hasMany(contratos_empresas) do contrato, não sei se ficou muito claro

Answer (score 1):

Você deve utilizar o seguinte formato:

1. Modelo: Empresas, tabela: empresas
2. Modelo: Contrato, tabela: contratos
3. No modelo de empresas: belongsToMany, contratos()
4. No modelo de contratos: belongsToMany, empresas()

Se você seguir esse modelo acima, você pode utilizar:

```
Empresa::with('contratos')->get();
// Ou vice-versa: Contrato::with('empresas')->get()
```

Isso vai retornar todas as empresas e contratos (relacionamento feito na tabela contratos_empresas - tabela pivot) + o contrato.

Provavelmente você vai ter que customizar a tabela pivot (por estar usando nomes em português).

Answer (score 1):

Fala ai cara blz?.
Seguinte, se o que você está querendo é somente os dados das empresas quando você puxar os dados do contrato, vc pode criar um appends (Atributo) dentro da classe contratos, onde ele vai puxar todos os dados das empresas. Assim:

Model de contratos crie a propriedade:

```
protected $appends = ['empresas'];
```

Agora, dentro da mesma model crie um method assim:

```
public function getEmpresasAttribute(){
   $empresa = ContratoEmpresas::select('empresa_id')
                                 ->where('contrado_id', '=', $this->id)
                                 ->value('empresa_id');
   return Empresas::find($empresa);
}
```

Avisando, o nome da função tem que ter o get no inicio e o Attribute no final, e no meio o nome do seu append, sempre começando com maiúsculo.

Com isso na sua classe, o append 'empresas' vira uma propriedade que estática que não está no seu banco de dados, e sempre ao acessar os dados da classe de contrato ele também vai mostrar essa propriedade junto.

Obs: Altere os nomes das table e das propriedades caso não seja iguais aos que usei.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' , olhei aqui e não consegui identificar a falta do ponto e vírgula

Comment: Realmente foi um errinho meu, mas já corrigi no código ai. Desculpas.

Answer (score 0):

Esse relacionamento chamamos de `many to many`, na documentação do laravel mostra como lidar com ele com o eloquent (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

No model de Contrato e de Empresa vai ter um método do Eloquent ORM que vai fazer essa relação pra voce e trazer um array com os elementos relacionádos.

No model de `Contrato` ficaria assim:

```
public function empresas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Empresa', 'contrato_empresas', 'contrato_id', 'empresa_id');
}
```

No model de `Empresa` ficaria assim:

```
public function contratos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contrato', 'contrato_empresas', 'empresa_id', 'contrato_id');
}
```

E para acessar basta chamar o método como atributo:

```
$empresa = Empresa::find($id);
$empresa->contratos;

$contrato = Contrato::find($id);
$contrato->empresas;
```